# If $E,F \in \mathcal L \implies E \bigcap F \in \mathcal L $ Caratheodory condition of measurability.

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

I will stop at the part I do not understand. Help is needed!

Caratheodory condition: For set $E\subset \mathbb R^n$ we will say that it satisfies the Caratheodory condition ili test measurability if $\forall A \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ applies:

$$m^*(A)=m^*(A \cap E) \cap ( A^c \cap E^c)$$

Lets take $E,F \in \mathcal L$

$$E \in \mathcal L \implies m^*(A)=m^{*}(A \cap E)+ m^{*}(A \cap E^c)\\
  F \in \mathcal L \implies m^*(A)=m^{*}(A \cap E \cap F)+ m^{*}(A \cap E \cap F^c)\\ \text{Since, $E \in \mathcal L,$ we have:*[ this is the step I do not understand]*}\\ m^*(A\cap (E \cap F)^c)=m^{*}(A \cap (E \cap F)^c\cap E)+ m^{*}(A \cap (E \cap F)^c\cap E^c)= \\ 
     m^{*}(A \cap F^c \cap E)+m^{*}(A \cap E^c).$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $E,F \in \mathcal{L}$ and let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, and let us write $m$ instead of $m^*$ for the outer measure.

So we must show that $m(A) = m(A \cap (E \cap F)) + m(A \cap( E\cap F)^c)$. We have $B = A \cap (E \cap F)^c \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and $E \in \mathcal{L}$, so we have
$$m(B) = m(B \cap E) + m(B \cap E^c) = m(A \cap (E \cap F)^c \cap E) + m(A \cap (E \cap F)^c \cap E^C).$$

Now, we have $(E \cap F)^c = E^c \cup F^c$, so
 $$(E \cap F)^c \cap E = (E^c \cap E) \cup (F^c \cap E) = F^c \cap E,$$
$$(E \cap F)^c \cap E^c = (E^c \cap E^c) \cup (F^c \cap E^c) = E^c.$$
Since in the first case $E\cap E^c = \emptyset$ and in the second case $F^c \cap E^c \subset E^c \cap E^c =E^c$.
So we have
$$m( A \cap (E \cap F)^c) = m(A \cap E \cap F^c) + m(A \cap E^c).$$

Then we find with your first two equalities
\begin{align*}
m(A) &=m(A \cap E) + m(A \cap E^c)  \\
&=m(A \cap E \cap F) +  m(A \cap E \cap F^c) + m(A \cap E^c)  \\
&= m(A \cap (E \cap F)) + m(A \cap (E \cap F)^c)) 
\end{align*}